# Laravel : Creating default object from empty value When insertion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have problem about `Creating default object from empty value` on line `$analyses->result = 1.0;` I checked in my DB has all these column.

```
  $analysis = new Analysis;
  $analysis->psubid = '1';
  $analysis->subjectid = '1';
  $analyses->result = 1.0;
  $analyses->rtd = 2.0;
  $analyses->save();
  $Analysis = Analysis::all();
  return $Analysis;
```

Comment: typo here `$analyses->` should be `$analysis->`

Comment: you have your variable name messed up, `$analysis` and `$analyses`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initiating variable with `$analysis` name and using `$analyses` in some of statement. Use same name for all

```
$analysis = new Analysis;
  $analysis->psubid = '1';
  $analysis->subjectid = '1';
  $analysis->result = 1.0;
  $analysis->rtd = 2.0;
  $analysis->save();
  $Analysis = Analysis::all();
  return $Analysis;
```